# How can I set width & height of element, but only use whichever is greater depending on screen size?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website with a flexible layout. I have a background video, and I want to set it so that it has either 100% width OR 100% height. I only want the width OR the height to be used in any given situation, and I want the browser to choose whichever of the two dimensions would make the video the largest. I can't use min-height and min-width, because the video is significantly larger than the size of the screen, so I have to set an actual width and actual height, but I want the browser to switch between using width or height depending on the aspect ratio of the screen.

Does anyone know how this could be done? Ideally the solution would only use CSS and HTML, but if this can only be done with JavaScript, I'm open to any suggestions! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess [media queries](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/) is what you need

Answer (score 0):

Adding a meta tag with viewport as it's name and then setting position attribute in css might do it what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Combining min-width/height with viewport width/height:

CSS:

```
#backgroundVideo{
    min-height : 100vw; /* the height will always be at least as great as the viewport width */
    min-width : 100vh; /* the width will always be at least as great as the viewport height */
}
```